# Evaluation of an equation including Levi-Civita symbols

Tags: mesons

How can I obtain the result of the right-hand side in the Equation
\begin{equation}
 i\epsilon_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta} \varepsilon^{\mu(\pm)}_{2}\varepsilon^{\nu(\pm)}_{1} p^{\alpha}_{B} p_{1}^{\beta}=\pm m_{B} p_{c}
 \end{equation}
 where 
 \begin{align}
  p^{\mu}_{B }&=(m_{B},0,0,0),& \quad p^{\mu}_{1}&=(E_{1},0,0,p_{c}),\\
  \varepsilon_{1}^{\mu(\pm)}&=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(0,\mp1,-i,0\right),& \quad \varepsilon_{2}^{\mu(\pm)}&=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(0,\mp 1,+i,0\right)\\
     \varepsilon.p_{1}&=0,& \quad  \varepsilon.p_{B}&=\dfrac{m_{B} p_{c}}{m_{1}}, &\quad \epsilon_{0123}&=-1.
 \end{align}
 Here $B$ refer to the B-meson of momentum $ p_{B} $ also $ p $ and $ \varepsilon $ are the momentum and polarization vector of a vector meson.

Comment: The Levi-Civita tensor has 24 nonzero components. If you write out the 24 terms in the sum, all but two vanish because of components being zero in one or more of the four 4-vectors. I think you are missing a factor of $i$.

Comment: Only terms where $\alpha$ is 0 can contribute. Then only terms where $\beta$ is 3 can contribute. Then only terms where $\mu\nu$ is 12 or 21 can contribute.

Comment: how to decide 12 or 21 arrangement?

Comment: They both contribute, and are the only contributions.

Comment: thank you very much, it works.

Comment: Didn’t you end up with a factor of *i* that isn’t in your first equation?

Comment: yes, I missed it as you said before. Thanks for your help @G.Smith